# Boto3 list_endpoints_by_platform_application Next Token

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, boto3

I am trying to get all my SNS enpoints associated to my app, however the Boto3 function is not working:

```
   response = client.list_endpoints_by_platform_application(
        PlatformApplicationArn='string',
        NextToken='string'
    )
```

However I am getting the follwoing error:

```
ListEndpointsByPlatformApplication operation: Invalid parameter: NextToken Reason: token is invalid or expired"
```

It will not accept NextToken as a parameter which is required to get the next set of endpoints after the first 100.

Answer (score 0):

Boto3 can handle the pagination for you.  Something like this should work:

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_endpoints_by_platform_application')
page_iterator = pagination.paginate(PlatformApplicationArn='string')
for page in page_iterator:
    print(page['Contents'])
```